# Where do I save images uploaded from users in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

Where do I save images uploaded from users in node js. I save blogs in my mongodb but where do I save images uploaded from users because at this time I am saving images in base64 and that is not recommended.

Please suggest me some services to store images from users.

Comment: You can store in your server's space itself in some directory OR use external services such as s3 to store them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is to use a storage instead of a database for storing files.
 For example Amazon S3 or Google Storage bucket. When your user uploads the image, you send the image itself to the bucket, retrieve the URL, and save the image URL in your blog document instead. 
When you retrieve your image, for example on your blog "show" page, you add the blog.imageUrl (or whatever you called your field) to a img tag instead.
The implementation itself depends on which storage provider you go for, but usually when you upload something, you'll get a promise returned from the provider. The image URL is often available once you resolve the returned promise. You upload first, and update your blog document after.

Personally, I like using firebase Firestore. (which uses Google bucket) This makes everything very easy. You install the firebase npm module, and register a new firebase app. You can then create a function for uploading and storing images, something like this:

```
const uploadImage = (blogId, image) => {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`${blogId}`); // Reference to bucket
  storageRef.put(image)
    .then(() =>{
      storageRef.getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          console.log(url) // Gives you the URL to the uploaded image
          // You can update or create your blog entry in mongodb here,
          // and add the image url to the blog object.
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This both explains how you would solve what the asker is asking about, and gives a couple of providers/services where the asker can upload files.

Comment: Is there a free service for this

Comment: They all provide generous free tiers! The same applies to firebase, which is probably the easiest to setup and use. Check out www.firebase.com

Comment: Please accept this as the answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: Hey can you tell me the complete process to upload files to Firebase firestore, I have completed the process of creating the storage at firebase.com but now I need to upload files to firestore from the tinymce and return a url to tinymce.